# Exclude specific OUs from Password Expiration Notification

Tags: powershell, active-directory, passwords, azure-powershell

Quick question guys, I'm updating a PS script that notifies users when their AD password is about to expire to exclude/Omit certain OUs from the notification. **Example**: Exclude "**RemoteUsers**" and "**AppUsers**" I have created a variable `$Searchxyzbase="DC=example,DC=com"` at the beginning of the script followed by the following:

```
# Get Enabled Users From AD RemoteUsers and AppUsers OU
  Import-Module ActiveDirectory
  $users = get-aduser -SearchBase $Searchxyzbase -Filter {(enabled -eq $true) -and (passwordNeverExpires -eq $false)} |  -properties sAMAccountName, displayName, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, 
  PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress, lastLogon, whenCreated
  $DefaultmaxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge
```

I know I suppose to be passing the following but not sure exactly where in the code.

```
? {$_.distinguishedname -notmatch 'OU=RemoteUsers|OU=AppUsers'}
```

I added it as follows:

```
# Get Enabled Users From AD RemoteUsers and AppUsers OU
  Import-Module ActiveDirectory
  $users = get-aduser -SearchBase $Searchxyzbase -Filter {(enabled -eq $true) -and 
 (passwordNeverExpires -eq $false)} | ? {$_.distinguishedname -notmatch 'OU=RemoteUsers|OU=AppUsers'} -properties sAMAccountName, displayName, PasswordNeverExpires, 
  PasswordExpired, 
 PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress, lastLogon, whenCreated
 $DefaultmaxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge
```

When I execute the code, it runs and return the following error:

```
`Where-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'properties'.
At C:\code\ps.ps1:69 char:176
+ ... inguishedname -notmatch 'OU=RemoteUsers|OU=AppUsers'} -properties sAMAcco ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand`
```

Comment: Put it after whencreated, -properties is part of the Get-ADUser command

Answer (score 0):

Doug suggestion worked. Thanks